# "Visual saliency" auf Deutsch

Tags: translation, english-to-german, noun

Ich lese zurzeit ein Paper, in dem der Ausdruck "visual saliency" immer wieder vorkommt, z. B. im folgenden Kontext:

> In a user study, the authors evaluated in which way and how much the
>   **visual bottom-up saliency** [Itt05] of a scene can be altered to steer
>   the attention of a subject to a certain piece of information without
>   noticeable changes for the subject.

oder

> The third video shows the calculated **visual saliency** for the original
>   source video.

oder

> In this evaluation scenario the visual variable color is already used
>   by the gaze heatmap and therefore cannot be used for visualizing the
>   modulated **saliency** on top of the same video.

Ich habe als Übersetzung für "saliency" "das Herausragen" gefunden, kann mir aber keinen direkten Reim machen, wie man das jetzt am Besten auf Deutsch übersetzen würde. Gerade beim zweiten Beispielsatz oben "Das dritte Video zeigt das berechnete visuelle Herausragen des Originalvideos" klingt einfach nur falsch für mich.

Hat jemand Vorschläge, wie ich "Visual Saliency" und "Saliency" generell besser übersetzen könnte?

Comment: Gute Frage. Da müsste man wohl jemanden fragen, der sich mit der Sache auskennt. Da gibt es bestimmt auch im Deutschen einen Fachbegriff dafür. - Im zweiten Satz würde ich es als Laie mit "Hervorhebung" versuchen. Passt meiner Meinung nach auch zumindest im ersten Satz. - Je nach Kontext kann man wohl *saliency* mit *Betonung* übersetzen. Passt aber imho nicht im Kontext *visual saliency*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Umgangssprachlich: Hervorhebung oder Auszeichnung

Fachsprachlich: [Salienz](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salienz)